# C: Trying to create a point in a function with a struct

Tags: c, function

I'm a beginner and my teacher wants me to create a point with a custom function called createPoint and a struct that he wrote for us.

Here is the struct, which he put in a .h file:

```
//Define Structures shared across multiple files
typedef struct pt_struct{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;
```

I tried to make the function this way, but my IDE is saying the types don't match

```
Point createPoint(double x, double y){
    Point pt[2];
        pt[0] = Point.x;
        pt[1] = Point.y;
    return pt[2]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you have errors in the createPoint function (2 errors) listed below :

1. creating array of structs (2 structs) and trying to assign a double to structure type.
2. error in intializing a structure member! this is not the syntax to init structs data members. see fixes below:

```
Point createPoint(double x, double y){
        Point pt[2];  /*array of 2 structs ?? */ 
        pt[0] = Point.x;
        pt[1] = Point.y;
    return pt[2]; 
}
```

fix this to access the struct like this:

```
Point createPoint(double x, double y){
        Point pt; /*declaring pt of type point. one variable only mot an array.*/
        pt.x = x; /*init the struct members with the operator Structure and union member access*/
        pt.y = y;
    return pt; 
}
```